# Docker with userns-remap still writes into volumes as root

Tags: docker

I've configured docker service to use userns-remap. However, if I mount any folder as volume like this:

```
-v [directory on disk]:[directory in container]
```

Files created in such volume still belong to root user. For example:

```
# docker run -v `pwd`:/home/user ubuntu:latest touch /home/user/test_file
# ll
total 2
drwxr-xr-x 2 webuser webuser 3 Nov 23 04:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 webuser webuser 4 Nov 23 03:31 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    0 Nov 23 04:05 test_file
```

This is undesirable. I need that any files created/modified by root user in containers would belong to user 'webuser'. How can I achieve that?

Additional info.

```
# uname -a
Linux logoritmic.ru 5.15.0-89-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 30 20:42:41 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# id webuser
uid=120(webuser) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),1003(drive),1004(webuser)

# cat /etc/subuid
webuser:120:1
webuser:200000:65536

# cat /etc/subgid
webuser:1004:1
webuser:200000:65536

# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "userns-remap": "webuser"
}

# ll /var/lib/docker/
total 60
drwx--x--- 14 root webuser 4096 Nov 23 03:23 ./
drwxr-xr-x 47 root root    4096 Nov 21 00:06 ../
drwx--x--- 12 root webuser 4096 Nov 23 03:45 120.1004/
drwx--x--- 12 root  200000 4096 Nov 23 01:43 200000.200000/
drwx--x--x  4 root root    4096 Nov 21 00:06 buildkit/
drwx--x---  2 root root    4096 Nov 21 00:06 containers/
-rw-------  1 root root      36 Nov 21 00:06 engine-id
drwx------  3 root root    4096 Nov 21 00:06 image/
drwxr-x---  3 root root    4096 Nov 21 00:06 network/
drwx--x---  3 root root    4096 Nov 23 00:17 overlay2/
drwx------  4 root root    4096 Nov 21 00:06 plugins/
drwx------  2 root root    4096 Nov 23 00:17 runtimes/
drwx------  2 root root    4096 Nov 21 00:06 swarm/
drwx------  2 root root    4096 Nov 23 00:17 tmp/
drwx-----x  2 root root    4096 Nov 23 00:17 volumes/

# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-11-23 03:45:16 +04; 26min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 19200 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 21
     Memory: 25.6M
        CPU: 704ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─19200 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Nov 23 03:45:15 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:15.681277429+04:00" level=info msg="detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
Nov 23 03:45:15 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:15.681333754+04:00" level=info msg="User namespaces: ID ranges will be mapped to subuid/subgid ranges of: webuser"
Nov 23 03:45:15 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:15.695330031+04:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Nov 23 03:45:15 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:15.695451337+04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Nov 23 03:45:16 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:16.155008238+04:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP addres>
Nov 23 03:45:16 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:16.229348729+04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Nov 23 03:45:16 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:16.239180219+04:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit="24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1" graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.5
Nov 23 03:45:16 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:16.239211557+04:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Nov 23 03:45:16 logoritmic.ru dockerd[19200]: time="2023-11-23T03:45:16.266199324+04:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Nov 23 03:45:16 logoritmic.ru systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
lines 1-22/22 (END)
```

I've tried reloading services and rebooting server, no changes. I also tried to run filebrowser with this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  filebrowser:
    image: filebrowser/filebrowser:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8280:80"
    volumes:
      - /media/thevoid:/srv
      - type: bind
        source: ./filebrowser.db
        target: /database.db
      - type: bind
        source: ./filebrowser.json
        target: /.filebrowser.json
```

Any added files were owned by root as well.